# Problem getting size of a list because of deprecated code

Tags: java, undefined, deprecated

What I am trying to do is get the size of a list that I have created. However, I am getting an error stating that **"The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Dimension"**

```
 public static void printElements(List someList) {
        for (int i = 0; i<someList.size(); i++) {
              System.out.println(someList.get(i)); }
    }
```

however,in my code `size()` is deprecated. So it doesn't get the value of `someList`. I've turned off deprecated and restricted API but still not working.

Yeah I imported java.awt.list instead of java.util.list.

Comment: It looks like you are not using `java.util.List`. Can you specify which `List` implementation you are using?

Comment: We have no idea what your `List` class is. For some reason, the `size` method returns a `Dimension`, not an `int`. Why? No idea, we don't have any details. There might be an `int` representing the size inside of that `Dimension` object, but nobody knows what that is.

Comment: You imported the `java.awt.List` instead of the `java.util.List`. And use then `List<?> someList`.

Comment: Don't tag the question as [Solved], use the check mark to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: sorry didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue's related to the library that you imported:

use:

```
import java.util.List;
```

instead:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

.size() it's deprecated to awt.List

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. I will check it and fix it asap.